# How to animate CSS3 smoothly at a slow speed?

Tags: css

I am trying to make the clouds move at a slower speed to display it as a background for an image. When I slow them down however the clouds will move jaggedly. Is there any way to make the clouds move smoothly at a slow speed?

Here is my CSS:

```
.cloud_one {
    background: url(http://dev.websitesdepot.com/babymoon2/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/cloud.png);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300%;
    -webkit-animation: cloud_one 450s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloud_one 450s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cloud_one 450s linear infinite;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
    0% {
    left: 0
}
100% {
    left: -200%
}
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jj6oc0tg/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way I can force chrome to do subpixel rendering for a slow translation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097660/is-there-a-way-i-can-force-chrome-to-do-subpixel-rendering-for-a-slow-translatio)

Comment: Take a look into http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EyxPPm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating the `transform:translate3d(0,0,0)` to `transform:translate3d(-200%,0,0)` will have better results than the `left:0` to `left:-200%`

```
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
    0% { transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
  100% { transform: translate3d(-200%,0,0); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position:center;
```

try this.
if it doesn't work try experimenting with where you put the code